# What's the correct way to call JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, function, dom

In the following code, the function `writeMessage` is called without parenthesis. However it works fine but Is it a correct way of function calling in javaScript or its better to use parenthesis along with `writeMessage()`.

```
window.onload = writeMessage;

function writeMessage()
{
    document.write("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: As with many things, in JavaScript there is no 'correct' way to do something. There can be many ways to do the same thing, each with equal 'correctness'. More importantly than whether to use brackets or not, you should *always* put the opening curly bracket on the same line as the function declaration in JavaScript, which is different from other languages, but 'correct' in this sense

Answer (score 5):

`window.onload = writeMessage;` is not a call - it's an assignment. You assign the `writeMessage` function as the `onload` field of the `window` object. The actual call is performed (internally) as `window.onload()` which is equivalent to `writeMessage()` in your case.

Comment: Does this applies to the following code also? `<input id="one" type="button" onclick="writeMessage"`

Comment: @sandbox: No. What you write within an `onclick` *attribute* in the HTML effectively ends up being the body of a function, so if you wanted to call `writeMessage` there, you'd need the *call* `writeMessage` (e.g., `onclick="writeMessage();"`). But avoid using `onXYZ` attributes in your markup, there are better ways to hook things up.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if onclick is in javascript function...? eg: `document.getElementById("redirect").onclick = myFunction();`

Comment: @sandbox: in this case you don't need parentheses, since it is identical to the original one. You should tell between **object properties** and **DOM attributes**.

Comment: @sandbox: No parens when assigning it in JavaScript code. Again, think of the **attribute** text as being the body of a function. So if you had `function eventHandler() { /*... your code here ...*/}`, what would you put inside it to *call* your function? But in JavaScript code when you're assigning to a *property* like `onclick`, you're assigning a function reference to be called later. If you included the parens, you'd be calling it right then (again, just like any other time you call a function and use its return value).

Answer (score 2):

> In the following code, the function writeMessage is called without parenthesis.

Actually, it isn't. The code

```
window.onload = writeMessage;
```

does **not** call the function. It assigns the function to the `onload` property of `window`. Part of the process of loading the page in browsers is to fire the function assigned to that property (if any) once the loading process is complete.

If you wrote

```
window.onload = writeMessage();
```

what you'd be doing is calling `writeMessage` and assigning the *result* of the call to `window.onload`, just like `x = foo();`.

---

Note that the code you've actually quoted, which executes a `document.write` when the page loads, will wipe out the page that just loaded and replace it with the text "Hello world", because when you call `document.write` after the page load is complete, it implies `document.open`, which clears the page. (Try it [here](http://jsbin.com/aqoyoh); source code [here](http://jsbin.com/aqoyoh/edit).) In modern web pages and apps, you almost never use `document.write`, but in the rare cases where you do, it must be in code that runs as the page is being loaded (e.g., not later).

Answer (score 1):

the `()` is used to **EXECUTE** the function

when you write

window.onload = writeMessage;

you actually set a **delegate** ( `pointer` to a function to be executed) for which  - when the `onload` event will occour.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct already.

You don't need parenthesis because you're just storing the function in `window.onload`, not calling it yourself.